# Функция не только по клику но и по нажатию Enter

Tags: javascript, ajax

Как реализовать скрипт, срабатывающий от клика на `button` `on('click', function()` и по нажатию на клавишу Enter

```js
$(function() {
    $('.find-number').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'nomer='+$('.input-number').val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('.ajax-answer').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(thrownError);
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

В HTML класс прицеплен к ссылке по сути а не к кнопке

```
<div class="modal__header">
  <img class="img modal__img" src="img/example.png" alt="Пример">
  <div class="modal__text">
  <p class="ajax-answer">ВВЕДИТЕ НОМЕР (например, PVD-0093/2023-1125-1)</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form class="modal__action" action="/" method="post">
      <input class="input input-number" type="text" placeholder="PVD-0093/2023-" value="PVD-0093/2023-">
    </form>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn--orange btn--shadow find-number">НАЙТИ</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Повесить событие нажатия кнопки `keydown` и проверяйте, что нажата кнопка Enter(keyCode = 13)

Comment: Если кнопка будет в фокусе - `click` все равно сработает. Если же твоя "кнопка" на самом деле вовсе не кнопка - значит нужно определить некоего родителя, на котором нужно перехватывать событие "нажатия клавиатуры". Таких событий так же несколько... Сделай полный пример с `html`, дабы было видно с чем ты имеешь дело.

Comment: В HTML класс прицеплен к ссылке по сути а не к кнопке, наверно стоит обычную форму кнопки применять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном примере нажатие на кнопку Enter на странице будет вызывать событие клика по кнопке.

```
$("body").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $(".find-number").click();
    }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Помогло. От себя добавлю еще, что при настройке событии на форму (<form>) она и ведёт себя как форма (капитан очевидность :))) Т.е.,  после нажатия на enter симулирует отправку формы и обновляет страницу.  Пришлось добавить после метода отключение стандартной реакции и было мне счастье <form method="post" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) return false;">